# XSLT Variable not working in xsl:value-of select=

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

I am working on some XSLT and I created a variable that will be used in a loop that will increment the index as it loops through, so the $index is the variable.

Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="module/name[@ID='SDCModule001']/title "/></title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="module/name[@ID='SDCModule001']"/>                
            </body> 
        </html> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template name="stepList" match="name">

        <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="total" select="numSteps" />

        <xsl:variable name="step" select="concat('step', $index)"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($index = $total)">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="step1" /><xsl:value-of select="$step" /></p>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I put the information in a paragraph on the page (`<p><xsl:value-of select="step1" /> - <xsl:value-of select="$step" /></p>`), I get:

Do this 1 - step1

"Do this 1" is what is read from the XML and is correct. I am not sure why `<xsl:value-of select="$step" />` is bringing back "step1" and not "Do this 1" because `<xsl:value-of select="$step" />` should translate into `<xsl:value-of select="step1" />`.

Any clue where I am going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: So which language do you use normally where you concatenate two values to form a string as a new variable value (as you do with e.g. `concat('step', $index)`) and then expect the variable reference (e.g. `$step`) to evaluate your string as code? You just get the string value you have created earlier, not sure where you got the idea that you have dynamic XPath evaluation. XSLT 3 has that with `xsl:evaluate` as an optional feature but I am sure you won't find any XSLT or XPath tutorial suggesting that your code should output anything but  the string `step1`.

Comment: In this very specific example, you could also do `<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = $step]" />`. However, it would be so much easier if the input XML could be changed, so instead of having `<step1>`, `<step2>` elements, you had `<step num="1">`, `<step num="2">` etc.

Comment: Note that this question looks very similar to this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100151/get-value-of-child-nodes-in-xslt , so perhaps taking that approach (by doing `<xsl:for-each select="steps/*" />`) will help you here?

Answer (score 2):

XSLT is not a macro language.

In a macro language, variables hold fragments of expression text, so if $x contains the text "delete file 'z'", then evaluating $x causes a file to be deleted.

XSLT is a conventional expression language in which variables hold values. Evaluating a variable containing the text "delete file 'z'" simply returns that text, it does not cause any files to be deleted. Similarly, if the value of variable $v1 is "$v2", the result of the evaluation is the string "$v2", not the contents of variable $v2.