# Get value of child nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child

I am very new to XML and XSLT but I am trying to create a HTML page that loops through a varying length of steps and produces a list in HTML.

The XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <module>
        <name ID="SDCModule002">
            <role>SDC</role>
            <modNum>002</modNum>
            <title>Test</title>
            <audience>me</audience>
            <numSteps>7</numSteps>
            <steps>
                <step1>Do this 1</step1>
                <step2>Do this 2</step2>
                <step3>Do this 3</step3>
                <step4>Do this 4</step4>
                <step5>Do this 5</step5>
                <step6>Do this 6</step6>
                <step7>Do this 7</step7>
            </steps>
        </name>
        <name ID="SDCModule003">
            <role>SDC</role>
            <modNum>003</modNum>
            <title>Hi</title>
            <audience>you</audience>
            <numSteps>4</numSteps>
            <steps>
                <step1>Hi</step1>
                <step2>There</step2>
                <step3>You</step3>
                <step4>Guys</step4>
            </steps>
        </name>
    </module>
</xml>
```

I have it so the information like Title, audience, task etc. are displayed for the module I am searching so that works.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/xml">
<html>
<head>
<title><xsl:value-of select="module/name[@ID='SDCModule001']/title "/></title>
</head>

<xsl:apply-templates select="module/name[@ID='SDCModule001']"/>

</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="stepList" match="name">


<div id= "info">
<center>

<font face="verdana" size="2"><b><center><xsl:value-of select="title" /></center></b></font>
<hr></hr>

<xsl:value-of select="audience" />
<p></p>
<xsl:value-of select="numSteps" />

</center>

</div>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think I need to have a `<xsl:for-each>` that lists the steps in an ordered list, so SDCModule002 will have 7 steps, and SDCModule003 will only have 4, or do I just get the values of all child nodes of the parent `<steps>`?

I don't want to do 15 if statements saying "if numSteps is 1, then do this.... if numSteps is 2, then do that" etc... I can and it would work but I am not sure if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

**Edited**

The expected results would be like this:

Module: SCDModule001
Title: Test
Audience: Me
Steps:
1. Do this 1
2. Do this 2
3. Do this 3
4. Do this 4
6. Do this 5
7. Do this 6
8. Do this 7

Comment: There is no `SCDModule001` in your input.

Comment: Hi, yes I removed that because it was long (had 15 steps in the XML code), but in my original, it is there. I picked the 002 and 003 because they were shorter.... sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating an `xsl:for-each` above the `step?` elements could look like the following. I also changed some the `xsl:apply-templates` to show all `module/name`s in the output. The output is not pretty, but should give you a good start. Don't forget to add an

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xslt" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

line to your XML to run it in the browser.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="text()" />

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>***<xsl:value-of select="module/name[@ID='SDCModule002']/title "/>***</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="module/name"/>
        </body> 
    </html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="steps">
    <div id= "info">
        <center>
            <font face="verdana" size="2">
                <b>
                    <center>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../title" />
                    </center>
                </b>
            </font>
            <hr />
            <xsl:value-of select="../audience" />
            <p></p>
            <xsl:value-of select="../numSteps" />
            <ol>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ol>
        </center>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In Firefox, the output looks like this:

[image: Output image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a great start. I want to have each one on a separate page so I want to have all SCDModule001 on one page and not show both, but I think I can figure that out. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you should avoid the use of xsl:for-each when it's not needed. Although it does not really matter, performance wise, for small translations or projects. The added benefit of apply-templates is that you only have to change the xpaths if the input is changed during realisation.

Here's an example which creates 2 html files per module. The template what matches "steps" is an extra, you don't need it to make it work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="module/name"/>
</xsl:template>
<!--Each name is a file - but can easily changed to module -->
<xsl:template match="name">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>***<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>***</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id= "info">
                <center>
                    <font face="verdana" size="2">
                        <b>
                            <center>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                            </center>
                        </b>
                    </font>
                    <hr />
                    <xsl:value-of select="audience" />
                    <p></p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="steps"/>
                </center>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!--Extra match for styling - steps can also directly be called from "name" template-->
<xsl:template match="steps">
    <xsl:value-of select="numSteps" />
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="steps"/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<!--Wildcard - matches all step nodes-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="steps">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*As a rule of thumb you should avoid the use of xsl:for-each when it's not needed.*" There is no such rule. You should use `xsl:for-each` whenever it's convenient to do so (and it often is).

Comment: That's what a rule of thumb is, isn't it? It's not a written rule but in practise it's more elegant. In general to get the best out of XSLT, is to use pattern matching as much as possible. Anyway that's not really the discussion here, and each to their own of course.